# error: could not convert 'tab' from 'vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >>' to 'vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>'

Tags: c++

here is my code which write a **column j** of a **board t** in an other **board tab**! I am a beginner so I don't understand the problem :(

```
    vector<string> colonne(vector<vector<string>> t, int j) {
    vector<vector<string>>tab;
    for(int i=0; i<t.size(); i++){
        for(int n=0; n<=j; n++){
            if(n == j){
                tab[n]=t[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

here is the message from the terminal:

```
error: could not convert 'tab' from 'vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >>' to 'vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>'
```

Comment: if someone can help me...

Comment: A `vector<vector<string>>` is not the same as a `vector<string>`.  Your return type is `vector<string>`.  I am inclined to close this question as a typo.

Comment: This code has numerous problems. It's hard to know how to suggest a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has numerous problems. I think (based on your description) that the code you are trying to write is this

```
 vector<vector<string>> colonne(vector<vector<string>> t, int j) {
    vector<vector<string>> tab(t.size());
    tab[j]=t[j];
    return tab;
}
```

The code above creates a new board `tab` with the same number of columns as the first board. It then copies one column (with index `j`) from the first board to the second board and then returns the second board.

Notice though that all the other columns in the new board will have size zero. That seems strange to me, but maybe it is what you want. If not then let me know and I try to make improvements.